# Show that Limit of this sequence is $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

If $\{a_n\}$ is a cauchy-sequence. Show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n-a_{n+1}|=0$$

It makes intuitive sense, I tried by substituting
$b_n := a_n-a_{n+1}$ , but couldn’t get an answer.

I should note that we are dealing with the set of rational numbers $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: This is direct from the definition of "Cauchy sequence".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then, by definition, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that
$$|a_n - a_m| \leq \varepsilon$$
for all $n,m \geq N$. Letting $m = n + 1$ yields that
$$|a_n - a_{n+1}| \leq \varepsilon,$$
which is precisely what we wanted to show.